# OpenCV erode what kernel to choose?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, kernel

I'm trying to erode my image:
[image]

in order to get something close to this (my goal):
[image]

I use this basic kernel of OpenCV

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
image_1 = cv2.erode(gray_overlay, kernel, iterations=1)
```

I know there are custom kernels, I have tried kernels with different weights, different sizes, but I can't get a satisfactory result (separation of squares without losing too much white surface)

Could someone advise me on a kernel?

Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use wide and short kernel (shape of a horizontal line).

By trial and error, I found that kernel size 21x2 gives the best results (if don't care about overfitting the kernel to the input).

For keeping the white surface, you need to apply eroding and then dilation.
The morphological operation of eroding and than dilation is named "closing".

---

Here is a code sample:

```
import cv2

gray_overlay = cv2.imread("image.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as grayscale.

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 2))

# Erode then dilate
image_1 = cv2.erode(gray_overlay, kernel)
image_2 = cv2.dilate(image_1, kernel)

# Erode then dilate is called "open"
image_3 = cv2.morphologyEx(gray_overlay, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


cv2.imshow('gray_overlay', gray_overlay)
cv2.imshow('image_1', image_1)
cv2.imshow('image_2', image_2)
cv2.imshow('image_3', image_3)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Results:

`image_1` (after erode):
[image]

`image_2` (after erode and dilate):
[image]

`image_3` (after closing):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about the specific shapes of the boxes and only care about the gaps between them, you should try morphological opening instead of applying erosion only.

Try this:

```
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread("image.png")
kernel = np.ones((9, 9), np.uint8)
eroded_image = cv.erode(image, kernel, iterations = 2)
dilated_image = cv.dilate(eroded_image, kernel, iterations = 2)
```

You can adjust the size of the kernel and the number of iterations to manipulate the final output.

You can also use:

```
cv.morphologyEx(image, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```